# Extract Notes and Contents of another Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheet spreadsheet that has cells including notes. I want to extract the notes and the contents of another cell. I am including a link to a test document I made to explain my issue. To pull data, I would like to extract the notes from column D (for my example the notes are showing the status of the sale) and I want to also extract the contents of Column B that have a cell note in Column D. I want to pull data that averages the status of sale per type of pet. To do this, I would want the end product to be a side by side list that looks like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rgbjqGRwS1yR_cHqjQQi3uBB0_ZcNraMNgtUZHQP9MY/edit?usp=sharing

| Column G | Column H |
| --- | --- |
| Dog | Sold |
| Cat | Sold |
| Fish | In Progress |

I can run a script that lists out all of the notes but it doesn't contain any text from the cell to show where the note is located. I can also create a function that extracts the note into a cell, but I would still have to go one by one to extract the notes.

Any help would be AMAZING!

Current Sheet looks like this:

| Type of Pet | Age | Breed | Pet Stores |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | 8 mos | Tabby | Petsmart |
| Dog | 1 year | Golden Retriever | Humane Society |
| Fish | 3 mos | Goldfish | Petco |
| Dog | 9 mos | Lab | Humane Society |
| Cat | 3 mos | Calico | Petsmart |
| Fish | 2 mos | Clownfish | Petco |
| Dog | 3 years | Yorkie | Humane Society |

I have notes on "Golden Retriever", "Calico", and "Clownfish"

Comment: Please provide all information required to answer the question in the question- [I do not follow links to offset resources. Please provide data in a markdown table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/206484)

Comment: I had notes on "Golden Retriever", "Calico", and "Clownfish"  @Cooper                                                       Type of Pet Age         Breed                 Pet Stores
Cat                8 mos Tabby                 Petsmart
Dog                1 year Golden Retriever Humane Society
Fish                3 mos Goldfish                 Petco
Dog                9 mos Lab                         Humane Society
Cat                3 mos Calico                 Petsmart
Fish                2 mos Clownfish         Petco
Dog                3 years Yorkie                 Humane Society

Answer (score 0):

This will extract the data that you wish.  But it's not clear to me what you wish to do with it.

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(3,2,sh.getLastRow() - 2, sh.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues();
  const ns = sh.getRange(3,4,sh.getLastRow() - 2).getNotes().flat();
  let o = vs.map((r,i) => {
    return ns[i] ? [r[0],ns[i]]: '';
  }).filter(e => e);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

Comment: Hi! When I put your script into the sheet, I get the following error                     
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')
myfunk @ Code.gs:4

Comment: You might need to change the sheet name.

Comment: I also updated the question to include what the sheet looks like @cooper

Comment: That gave me the note and the contents of the cell the note is on! Is there any way to get the note and the contents of the cell two columns over from it? I want it to show that the "Dog" in row 3 is associated with the note in row 3

Comment: Please provide me with a markdown table of the data.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, I included a table of it :)

Comment: Okay that should do it.